# The requested resource (/StrutsApp/welcm.jsp) is not available

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

> On submitting the form I'm getting double slash in the url http://localhost:8090/StrutsApp//JSPS/registration.action 
>   I guesss there is some problems with the struts.xml configuration.
>   folder structure WebContent/JSPS/welcm.jsp and WebContent/JSPS/error.jsp.
>   After submitting the form I want display success/error page accordingly

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
       "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
     <struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />  
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />  
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="myapp" />    
    <package name="JSPS" extends="struts-default" namespace="/JSPS">    
        <action name="registration" class="com.action.RegistrationAction">
            <result name="success">/welcm.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>  
        </action>       
    </package>  
</struts>
```

Comment: Did your action execute after you have submitted the form?

Comment: thanks for your comment. Actually i was doing mistake in result configuration. I was giving /welcm.jsp instead of /JSPS/welcm.jsp

Comment: What is the question then?

Comment: Actually I was not getting success page after inserting the value into database..... Now I'm getting..... 
Thanks for taking interest